# Print multiple pdf's at once, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple pdf's. With one button I want to open print preview for all documents seperately. The solution can be in javascript or jquery.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, you cannot open multiple print dialogs. Instead, you can open them sequentially. The easiest way to print PDFs in Javascript is with [PrintJS](https://printjs.crabbly.com/)

Here's a recursive example that prints an array of PDFs.

```
var documentURLs = ["https://example.com/pdf1.pdf", "https://example.com/pdf2.pdf"]
function printDocuments(index){
   if(index > documentURLs.length){
        return;
   }
   printJS({
     printable: documentURLs[index],
     type: 'pdf',
     onPrintDialogClose: function () {
        printDocument(index+1)
     }
   })
}
```

You'd start it with `printDocuments(0)`. Be sure to download and include the PrintJS library with `<script src="print.js"></script>`

Comment: The index is not incrementing, it always print the same document

Comment: It should be `printDocument(index + 1)` to work properly

Comment: Updated, thank you @Pointy